# Turn a fits file into healpix map

Tags: python, healpy

I created a fits file. It is just a 2D array, I can visualize it using `plt.imshow(fits.getdata(my_file))`. Is there a way to turn it into a healpix map? If yes, please provide a detailed answer. If no, please explain why. Any help appreciated!

I am aware of `healpy.fitsfunc.write_map(filename, m)` but I struggle with using it (cannot set the m parameter) and do not know if this function is any help with my task

Answer (score 0):

The `hp.write_map` function is only to write a pre-existing healpix map from memory into a fits file.

From your question, It is not clear what sort of data you have. But assuming that you have a 2d grid of data since you use `imshow`. You need to convert it to a healpix map before you use `hp.write_map`.

Depending on your coordinate system, you need to know the coordinates of each of the grid points, to convert the grid into healpix map.

To convert some data (scalar) into a healpix map, after finding the coordinates,  You can write a function like this, which takes the coordinates and makes a healpix map for you.

```
def make_map_vec(theta, phi, data):
    assert len(theta) == len(phi) == len(data)
    e1map = np.full(hp.nside2npix(NSIDE), hp.UNSEEN, dtype=np.float)
    index = hp.ang2pix(NSIDE, theta, phi)
    values = np.fromiter((np.sum(data[index==i]) for i in np.unique(index)), float, count=len(np.unique(index)))
    e1map[np.unique(index)] = values
    return e1map
```

[This](https://healpix.sourceforge.io/html/csub_Conventions.htm) link gives you the coordinate system used by healpix.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, I want to plot a 2d array in mollweide projection.
My 2d array is a 180*360 array, using matplotlib.pyplot. imshow the axis don't follow the projection:
[image]

so to resolve this problem I want to use mollview of healpy but I don't know to convert my 2d array Data(180*360) into an object that mollview could plot.

In the previous answer, you assume data is 1D array having same length as theta and phi. I tried to test it doing this :

```
test = np.ones((180,360))
data = test.reshape(180*360)
theta = []
phi = []
for i in range (360):
    for j in range (180):
        theta.append((j)*np.pi/180)
        phi.append((i)*np.pi/180)

theta = np.asarray(theta)
phphi = np.asarray(y)

def make_map_vec(theta, phi, data):
    assert len(theta) == len(phi) == len(data)
    e1map = np.full(hp.nside2npix(NSIDE), hp.UNSEEN, dtype=np.float)
    index = hp.ang2pix(NSIDE, theta, phi)
    values = np.fromiter((np.sum(data[index==i]) for i in np.unique(index)), float, count=len(np.unique(index)))
    e1map[np.unique(index)] = values
    return e1map

map_test = make_map_vec(theta,phi,data)
hp.mollview(map_test,title="Mollview image RING")
```

I got :

[image]

which is not correct.

Do you know if there is any other way to get a map from a 2D array?